# ListBox display selected Items (Image) in another ListBox (Selection Mode Multiple)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I'm just trying to experiment some `ListBox` functionality in the `SelectionChanged` event.

I have the following controls:

1.ListBox : Name = ListBoxSource    (I just added the `Image` in XAML)

2.ListBox : Name = ListBoxDisplay

I just want to iterate and get those items selected from `ListBoxSource` and display it to `ListBoxDisplay`. How to do that in the Loop?

The Items on the `ListBoxSource` are only `Image` controls and no other controls.

I cannot find any solutions on the net because most of the examples/solutions are using `TextBlock`, `TextBox`, or `CheckBox` ...and no `Images`.

```
foreach (Object selectedItem in ListBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    // What to do in here to add the selected Images to "ListBoxDisplay"
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a loop for that. Did you try to simply bind ListBoxDisplay.Items to ListBoxSource.SelectedItems?

Comment: @Martin: Yes I did try that one. 
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxSource, Path=SelectedItems}"
But No display on "ListBoxDisplay"

Comment: @H.B: Yes..I mean I find it hard to follow even if the examples are using TextBlock or other controls because I think It can display a string which is the default of those type of controls. Mine are Images

Comment: You make a false assumption, the items can be absolutely anything and if it's something that can be displayed the ListBox will show it.

Comment: Use:  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxSource, Path=SelectedItems}" instead of DataContext="..."

Comment: @Erno: Thank you.. Binding it to ItemSource works...It appears to be Okay now., BUT Im still wondering now if it is necessary to transfer the Images to the "ListBoxDisplay"? Because the Images on the "ListBoxSource" are gone every time I select an item(image).

Comment: That is a different question. What do you mean: "are gone"? Are they back when you deselect them? If so your ItemTemplate might be wrong.

Comment: Ah, notice that you can add a UI control just once to the visual tree.  (In this regard Silverlight is a bit different from WPF, are you using SL or WPF?)\

Comment: Im using WPF.. someone just Edit my post I specify it in my title. anyway.. I did comment to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxDisplay"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxSource, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
```

instead of all that code.

Also: Use a DataTemplate and DataBinding to fill the ListBoxes that will make this construction much more robust and flexible.

Comment: This works...thank you.. So you think my ItemTemplate is wrong? There is no problem in selecting and deselecting an item on my "ListBoxSource" ONLY the selected items are gone(maybe not displaying).. I mean literally the image are no longer displaying for those selected items.

Comment: Do they still take screenspace?

Comment: Yes..there are still screenspace.. the selecting and desecting of item are working fine and displays exactly the selected items BUT the first time you select an item the image is gone the selection highlights remain but has no more image in it. (You can still deselect though even if no more image because the space is still there)

Comment: I raise another question with regards to this and posted my code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563164/no-more-displayed-image-on-listbox-everytime-i-select-an-item

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<ListBoxSource.Items.Count;i++)
{
   Image currentImageItem = ListBoxSource.Items[i] as Image;
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = currentImageItem.Source ; 
   ListBoxDisplay.Items.Add(image);
}
```

Sorry for my mistake this code should work 
you must handle other properties like width and height

Comment: I got an Error using the above code:
"Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one"

Comment: @user1078782: That is why you should avoid having lists of UI-elements.