# No more displayed image on ListBox everytime I select an item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

**PROBLEM:**

I got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561678/listbox-display-selected-items-image-in-another-listbox-selection-mode-multip) when doing some binding from ListBoxSource to ListBoxDisplay **BUT** weird thing happened:

The selecting and deselecting of items are working fine and displays exactly the selected items on the other ListBox named "ListBoxDetails **BUT** everytime I select an item the image is gone but selection highlights remain but has no more image in it. (You can still deselect it though even if no more image because the screenspace is still there)

**NOTE:** I have no other control inside the ListBoxSource (SelectionMode=Multiple) ONLY Image

**CODE XAML:**

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Height="149" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="193">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Width="180" Margin="0"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate2">
        <UniformGrid x:Name="UniformGridImageList"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxSource" Width="450" Margin="9,3,442,178"  ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate2}" SelectionMode="Multiple" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />     
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxDisplay" Height="659" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="460,5,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxSource, Path=SelectedItems}" />
    <Button x:Name="buttonLoadImages" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="33,0,0,70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="183" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" Click="buttonLoadImages_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Clear" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,717,442,0" Name="buttonClearListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" Click="button1_Click" />

</Grid>
```

**CODE C#:**

above declaration:

```
 private List<Image> _imageList = new List<Image>();
```

.
.
.

```
        private void buttonLoadImages_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this._imageList = GetImageList(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures");


        foreach (Image curImage in this._imageList)
        {

            ListBoxSource.Items.Add(curImage);

        }

    }

    #region GetImageList Method

    private List<Image> GetImageList(string strPath)
    {
        List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
        string strFilePath = "";

        if (Directory.Exists(strPath) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} path could not be found.", strPath));
            return imageList;
        }

        try
        {


            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
            FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg",SearchOption.AllDirectories);


            foreach (FileInfo curFile in files)
            {


                strFilePath = curFile.FullName;

                Image curImage = new Image();
                BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
                bmpImage.BeginInit();
                bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(curFile.FullName, UriKind.Absolute);
                bmpImage.EndInit();

                curImage.Height = 140;
                curImage.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

                curImage.Source = bmpImage;
                curImage.Margin = new Thickness(10);

                imageList.Add(curImage);
            }

            if (imageList.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("No image files could be found in {0}", strPath));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}-{1}", ex.Message, strFilePath));
        }

        return imageList;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBoxSource.Items.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Why is there a WrapPanel in the DataTemplate? How do you set the Image source? Could you post the C# code that loads the ListBox too?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Do you have anything else going on in your code or XAML?

Comment: Also, to get it working I am adding `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"` to both ListBoxes. I figured you were already doing that, but thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: @Erno: Just added my c# code behind

Comment: @Rachel: I did that already and it fixes the non-display of image issue but my "ListBoxDisplay" doesnt show anymore selected items binded from "ListBoxSource"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Image` UI objects and adding them directly to your ListBox.

This means that the `SelectedItems` is an `Image` UI object, so ListBox #2 is trying to set it's `Items` to the exact same `Image` object reference. This isn't allowed in WPF because UI objects can only have a single parent, however because it is a Binding error, WPF is silent about it (except for probably a warning)

I would recommend making your `List<Image>` into a `List<string>` which contains the path name for the image, and changing your `<Image>` in the template to use that string as it's Source. Also, don't forget to set the `ItemTemplate` on both your ListBoxes.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <WrapPanel Height="149" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="193">
        <Image Source="{Binding }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Width="180" Margin="0" />
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I did a quick test and it works fine once you fill your ListBoxes with Strings instead of UI objects